# Python3 Beautiful Soup get HTML tag anchor

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BS4 and Python to save and replace the content of the first `<translate>` tag in a HTML file.

Now I am trying to do something like this:

```
translate_bs4 = bs4_object.find('translate')
translate_key = '{{ key }}'
translate_initial = str(title_bs4)
translate_bs4.string = translate_key
```

My test case is:

```
<translate>tag with <other_tag>some text</other_tag></translate>
<much_longer_file>...</much_longer_file>
```

and the HTML is the expected one of:

```
<translate>{{ key }}</translate>
<much_longer_file>...</much_longer_file>
```

but the value of `translate_initial` is

```
<translate>tag with <other_tag>some text</other_tag></translate>
```

instead of expected

```
tag with <other_tag>some text</other_tag>
```

I know that it can be easy extracted with a regex, but I want a some more DOM-related solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
translate_bs4 = bs4_object.find('translate')
translate_initial = translate_bs4.decode_contents(formatter="html")
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I got some problems with some non-ASCII characters that has no equivalent HTML entity. Solved that by setting formatter to None. Thank you! :D